# Local variable declaration swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm trying to allow for a user to send an email in my app but I get a:

> Use of local variable 'configureMailComposeViewController' before its declaration

Here is the code.

```
func item(_ item: Int, selectedAtContactIndex index: Int) {
    var mailComposeViewController = configuredMailComposeViewController()
    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        self.presentViewController(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {

    }
}

func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController{
    let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self

    mailComposerVC.setToRecipients([EmailAddressArray[index]])
    mailComposerVC.setSubject("I need your help")

    return mailComposerVC
}
```

[image: Image of the Error]

Comment: Unrelated by why do you call `configuredMailComposeViewController` before you call `if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()`?

Comment: @john, how do you think this mean? `MFMailComposeViewController()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController
```

**This right here is your function that has a return type `MFMailComposeViewController` which you will get when you will call this method.It will return you some result**

**Now the result from your above method `func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewControllercall` need to be saved in a variable you just can not leave it to fly in the air .In order to save or get what ever this method does you need to do this -:**

```
var mailComposeViewController = configuredMailComposeViewController()
```

**So this makes it clear you need to call this  `mailComposeViewController = configuredMailComposeViewController()` after your return function not before.**

**Exactly this-:**

```
    func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController{
        let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self

        mailComposerVC.setToRecipients([EmailAddressArray[index]])
        mailComposerVC.setSubject("I need your help")

        return mailComposerVC
    }





        func item(_ item: Int, selectedAtContactIndex index: Int) {

        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
var mailComposeViewController = configuredMailComposeViewController()
            self.presentViewController(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {

        }
    }
```

Comment: And you really should move the line `var mailComposeViewController = configuredMailComposeViewController()` to inside the `if` statement. It makes no sense to create the mail composer if you can't send email.

Answer (score 0):

Switch the order of the functions , put `configuredMailComposeViewController` function on top

```
    func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController{
    let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self

    mailComposerVC.setToRecipients([EmailAddressArray[index]])
    mailComposerVC.setSubject("I need your help")

    return mailComposerVC
}





    func item(_ item: Int, selectedAtContactIndex index: Int) {
    var mailComposeViewController = configuredMailComposeViewController()
    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        self.presentViewController(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused can you make an edit to show me what your talking about